# Exclusion of spring security from spring Activiti starter is causing spring secutiry issues

Tags: spring, spring-security, activiti

I have excluded spring security from activiti boot starter . but it is still referring spring security classes.

```
               <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.0.M4</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>

                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
```

I am getting below error after exclusion of Spring security dependency.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [com.infy.activitidrools.ActivitiDroolsApplication]; nested exception
>   is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]
>   cannot be opened because it does not exist
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:596)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:108)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:805)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:801)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:771)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
>             at com.infy.activitidrools.ActivitiDroolsApplication.main(ActivitiDroolsApplication.java:10)
>   ~[classes/:na]

Comment: So you are excluding spring-security because you are adding your own spring-security dependency right?

Comment: Thank you! . I am not adding spring Security. is spring Security mandatory to use Activiti 7 ?

Comment: I dont know i would asume that since its a dependency :P havent tried Activiti 7 yet. why are u excluding it?

Comment: I am migrating the Activiti 5 to 7 .  spring security never been used in legacy app. I really wonder Activiti 7 is stable . it's behaving crazy .